# Bootstrap: How to modify header when accordion is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason, my accordion pushes up my header when it is active. I am wondering the best way to go about fixing this, is it possible to add a class to the header when the accordion is active to move it's position down (margin-top)?

I am using the default bootstrap.js and jquery.js files. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img class="header-logo" style="" src="">SF</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Retrospective</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[image: This is what it looks like active]

[image: And this is the header normally]

These images are the header with the accordion active/normal.